# How to get the inline style of a custom css var with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline-styles

How can I get the inline style of a custom CSS var from an element?
I can easily get the width or any other traditional styles but get an error when I try to get the custom inline style.   Is there a way to extract this style data?  Thank you in advance for any help provided.  No jQuery Please.

```js
var styleDivWidth = document.getElementById('myId').style.width;
console.log(styleDivWidth);

/*
var styleDivRotation = document.getElementById('myId').style.--rotation;
console.log(styleDivRotation);
*/
```

```css
.myClass{
background-color:red;
float:left; 
--rotation: 45deg;
transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
margin:20px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="myId" class="myClass" style="width:100px; height:100px;
 --rotation:-45deg;">
```

Comment: you probably have to get the value of the `transform` property and parse out the value

Comment: note that inline styles are always more specific that external one so you question can simply be *how to read value of custom property* and the answer is easier that what you are getting here. A simple computedStyle and you get it

Comment: thank you @TemaniAfif you were right i found a much better solution with the links you posted at the top..    var styleRotation = document.getElementById('myId').style.getPropertyValue('--rotation');

Comment: **SOLUTION:** to get the value of inline css variable `--my-var` from `myElement`, you can use: [`getComputedStyle(myElement).getPropertyValue('--my-var')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue).  It always returns a string so if you need a number, wrap the above in a [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract this by parsing the `cssText` property.

Here's some code and JsFiddle below:

```
const cssText = document.getElementById('myId').style.cssText;
console.log(cssText);
const rotationProp = cssText.split("; ").find(style => style.includes("rotation"));
console.log(rotationProp);

const rotationValue =  rotationProp.slice(rotationProp.indexOf(":") + 1, rotationProp.indexOf(";"));
console.log(rotationValue);
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ajp1cug/

Comment: that's a lot of code compared to [`getComputedStyle(myId).getPropertyValue('--rotation')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript).

Answer (score 1):

```
var rotation = document.getElementById("myId").style.cssText.split("--rotation:")[1];
rotation = rotation.substring(0, rotation.length - 1);
console.log(rotation);
```

Comment: Easier: [`getComputedStyle(myId).getPropertyValue("--rotation")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript).

Answer (score 1):

I made a function that will do it :

```js
function getAttributeValueFromStyles(stylesText, attributeName){
   var attrParts = stylesText.split(';');
   var attrIndex = attrParts.findIndex(function(part){
    return part.split(':')[0] === attributeName;
   });
   return attrParts[attrIndex].split(':')[1];
}
const element = document.querySelector('#test');
const style = element.getAttribute("style");
var attrValue = getAttributeValueFromStyles(style, "--rotation");
console.log(attrValue);
```

```html
<div id="test" style="background:red;--rotation:-45deg;color:white;">
 
</div>
```

I don't know but may be there is another way to do it with js available methods.

Comment: that's a lot of code compared to [`getComputedStyle(myId).getPropertyValue('--rotation')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript).